# Stored Procedure and C# SqlDataReader Returns Less Rows Than Expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatareader

I have been asked to migrate a website application from one server to another.
The code was written by previous developer.

He created a stored procedure with the following:
[Parameters]

```
            @SurveyPeriodConfigID int = -1,
            @StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
            @EndDate DATETIME = NULL,
            @StartTime DATETIME = [9:00:00],
            @EndTime DATETIME = [19:00:00],
            @Category INT = -1,
            @SubcategoryID INT = -1,
            @ReportType VARCHAR(50) = null,
            @DepartmentID INT = -1,
            @FloorID INT = -1,
            @RoomID INT = -1,
            @IsLazyLoad BIT = 0,
            @Day INT = -1
```

and [WHERE caluse]:

```
            SELECT [fields]
            FROM [tables]
            WHERE 
            (DATEPART(dw, rsdm.DateCreated)) != 7 AND (DATEPART(dw, rsdm.DateCreated)) !=1
                    AND rsdm.DateCreated BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
                    AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rsdm.DateCreated,108) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime)
                    AND (@Category = -1 OR rsdm.CategoryCodeID = @Category)
                    AND (@SubcategoryID = -1 OR rsdm.SubcategoryID = @SubcategoryID)
                    AND (@DepartmentID =-1 OR rsdm.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID)
                    AND (@FloorID =-1 OR rsdm.FloorID = @FloorID)
                    AND (@RoomID =-1 OR rsdm.RoomID = @RoomID)
                    AND (@Day =-1  OR  DATEPART(dw, rsdm.DateCreated) = @Day)
```

C# Code:

```
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

...calls the stored procedure and returns SqlDataReader.

So far so good.

Now the issue... previously the old site returned 8200 rows but now the new website returns 6500 rows!!!

I setup the code and website on my PC on my copy of sql database... it returns correct value of 8200. I then changed web.config to point to new website sql server... 6500 rows!!!

I backed up live site sql database and restored said same database locally on my PC and tested it... 8200 rows!!!

Old site had Sql server 2005, my PC has developer SQL 2012 whilst live server has SQL 2012.

I then ran sql profiler on new site Sql Server, extracted script and ran script on same sql database 8200 records!!!

I've spent the past 1-2 days on this and still no idea why live Sql Server return 6500 rows via sqldatareader.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but without the actual data it is almost impossible to answer this question.

Comment: is CS/CI (case-sensitivity) setting the same? are the ansi-null defaults the same?

Comment: OK was hoping someone would say it was something in SqlDataReader that i'm missing something. I've checked the data and it appears to be fine.

Comment: Start removing where clasues and see if you eventually get data, then add them in again and you'll figure out where it goes wrong

Comment: Why are you using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),rsdm.DateCreated,108) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime` ? casting dates via strings is never a good idea; what is the intent there? (note this does two casts - one implicit, one explicit - not good)

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen good point should really start playing with the where clause.

Comment: @MarcGravell - as I said previous developer wrote this. I think he's trying to check between times and dates. The CONVERT(, 108) is check the time.

Comment: @Rob that clause would be the one that interests me the most; I'd try using `cast(DateCreated as Time)`, for example. Also, is there any chance the `dw` is different? i.e. `DATEFIRST` is configured differently. You can check this with `select @@DATEFIRST`

Comment: @MarcGravell - the thing that gets me is that i can execute same procedure using SQL Management and it returns 8200! It's only with the sqldatareader!? I extracted the actual tsql from profiler and it works fine... just not with SqlDataReader! aaarghgh

Comment: @MarcGravell DATEFIRST is fine

Comment: @Rob "`DATEFIRST` is fine"... I'm going to whistle quietly there ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the database, there is always a login account associated with it. Are you using a different login for your app than you use when connecting with SQL Server Management Studio?  Date formats are based on the default language for your logins.

Please run the following query:

```
Select  syslogins.name, syslogins.language, syslanguages.dateformat
From    sys.syslogins
        Inner Join sys.syslanguages
            On syslogins.language = syslanguages.name
```

Check the dateformat column for all the logins returned.  If the dateformat is different, then this probably explains why you are getting different results when running from your app vs. running from SSMS.

If this truly is the cause of your problems, then you can change the default language for your logins by following the directions in this blog:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se/

Comment: Thankyou!!! Select  syslogins.name, syslanguages.datefirst
From    sys.syslogins
        Inner Join sys.syslanguages
            On syslogins.language = syslanguages.name
... helped!!!

Answer (score 3):

I would check if options are configured differently on the different servers, in particular ANSI_NULLS (see script below).  Note that when you run a script in SSMS, the default options are likely different to those in effect when using ADO.NET (see SSMS Tools / Options / Query Execution / SQL Server / ANSI).  This often explains differences in behavior between SSMS and ADO.NET.

```
DECLARE @options INT 
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS 

PRINT @options
IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```

Comment: 5496
ANSI_WARNINGS
ANSI_PADDING
ANSI_NULLS
ARITHABORT
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL

on both Sql 2012 servers

Comment: @Rob you need to run it **separately** from both SSMS and via `SqlClient`, against **separately** both servers - the point being to find *what is different*. SSMS does not use the same defaults as `SqlClient` (indeed, the SSMS options depend on your own user-specific options inside SSMS)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention the results are different between SSMS and `SqlClient`, there are two options I can think of

- there are actually 2 different sprocs in different schemas, and SSMS is choosing one and `SqlClient` the other (presumably based on identity)
- (much more likely) the `SET` options are different, causing different behavior

To check the latter, run `select @@OPTIONS` in both SSMS and via `SqlClient`, and compare. The flags are listed here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/

Comment: OK appreciate this. 5496 SSMS, 5492 SqlClient. What now? How is one different from each other?

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was with `(DATEPART(dw, rsdm.DateCreated)) != 7 AND (DATEPART(dw, rsdm.DateCreated)) !=1`

SqlClient user had DATEFIRST set as 1, where as my SSMS was 7. All other same user connections to other sql server instances had DATEFIRST set as 7. (Thanks also to @"G Mastros" for final confirmation of issue).

All I did was add SQL Script `SET DATEFIRST 7;` for now and will deal with why users are setup with 1 later!